# Remove 8pixel area that precedes xAxis values

Tags: highcharts

Can you help with the following please? I just can't find the solution.

On my chart, there is a small area (just 8 px) that precedes the start of my xAxis values. I would like to remove that area so my first xAxis value would be the start of the chart plot area.

Perhaps this image will help explain what I mean and the result I'd like.

[image: Remove area that precedes xAxis values]

Something tells me what I need is not hard to achieve. For the second image above, I have used

```
yAxis: {
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        offset: -8,
}
```

However, that is not the solution as the area is obviously still there. For this particular chart, I'd like to remove the area completely.

Alternatively, can I always take for granted that this area will be 8px? I mean  no matter what device the chart would be viewed on?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Ahhh ... a bit embarrasing ... it seems 'minPadding' maybe what I need ...

```
xAxis: {        
                minPadding: 0.0,
                ...
}
```

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan. I think I may have just come across the answer on the API docs ... minPadding. If this doesn't do what I need, I'll create a fiddle and update the question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use categories? If yes, minPadding doesnt work. Second solution is set startOnTick paratemer, if it will not solve your problem, please supply demo

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan. No, I'm not using categories, so minPadding seems to work OK. The yellow plotband on the image, slide left & right on my chart. It represents a way to select a portion of the time series. The problem I was having was that I needed to know where the 'From' value of the plotBand was after it had been moved (otherwise the export engine always rendered the plotBand with a from value of 0). Minpadding and chart.pointer.normalize will let me figure out the new value so I can remove and re-add the plotband in the correct place.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan. Do you want to make you comment into an answer? I can accept it, then.

Comment: I added, but its correct?

Comment: @SebastianBochan. Yes, I believe minPadding: 0 is correct and fixes my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `startOnTick` paratemer as true, or set `minPadding` as 0.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yysd1k1L/3/

Comment: minPadding is the solution for me. This allows me to use chart.pointer.normalize to track a move a plotBand and keep track of the bands from value. I can now remove and re-apply the band in order for the export engine to render the band in the new location, rather than it's original position.